# echo PHP array in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php

I know there are hundreds of questions on this, and I've done this before, but I just cant get it to work now. I need to pass a PHP array to a Javascript variable. This is what I'm doing:

```
var arr = <?php echo json_encode(array(1,2,3,4)); ?>;
```

This should work, but doesn't. I tried putting the PHP part in quotes, but that (as expected) makes no difference. Do I have to set some parameter with the Javascript tags(like src)? Could it be a problem with PHP version? All the other PHP parts work fine (I've commented them out one at a time: This is the problematic line). I even copied another StackOverflow answer to a similar question and that didn't work (just the one line).

I'm using XAMPP 1.7.4 and PHP 5.3.5 (if that affects this).

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? What is the actual output? Also, you should consider upgrading to at least PHP5.4 since PHP5.3 is no longer supported since 14 aug 2014. http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: What function_exists('json_encode') returns?

Comment: In wich file is this line of code located and what is the actual result?

Comment: Well, I'm displaying a canvas and some alerts after this line of code. When I comment out this line, I can see the canvas and all the subsequent alerts.
With this line, nothing loads.
This Javscript line is embedded in the html for the page.

Comment: But what does your browser receive, instead of `<?php echo ...` ? Look at the source code in your browser, and tell us what is there.

Comment: My PHP definitely supports json_encode (I've used it earlier in the program). I also tried it separately on an individual PHP file.

Comment: I just looked at the page source on Firefox. It says:
var arr = <?php echo json_encode(array(1,2,3,4,5)); ?>;

Comment: Then, it is not interpreted as PHP. Does this file have a PHP extension?

Comment: Yeah, the extension was the problem. Renaming the file got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just added this code to my php file under script tags and it works. On js file it doesn't work though, what's your filename?

Comment: I've put this Javascript in the html file. Its called fresh.html.

Comment: webservers generally only execute php if it's in a `.php` file. `.js` and `.html` files are NOT considered php scripts and threfore won't be processed through php and therefore php code in them will NOT be executed.

Comment: That works! All I did was change the file extension. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

place a hidden input tag and echo the php result into to value attribute and getElementById().value in your script.

```
<input id="array" type="hidden" value="<?php echo jason_encode(array(1,2,3,4));?>" />
```

`var arr = getElementById('array').value;`
or 
    `var arr = $.('#array').val();`